# AutoKey: Switch to last active application like Alt-Tab by using AutoKey

Tags: python, python-3.x, autokey

is it possible to send the alt+tab for switch to last window with AutoKey ?

i tried without success:

`keyboard.send_keys("<alt>+<shift>+<tab>")`

Or forward window:

```
keyboard.press_key('<alt>')
keyboard.press_key('<tab>')
keyboard.release_key('<tab>')
keyboard.release_key('<alt>')
```

Or backward window:

```
keyboard.press_key('<alt>')
keyboard.press_key('<shift>')
keyboard.press_key('<tab>')
keyboard.release_key('<tab>')
keyboard.release_key('<shift>')
keyboard.release_key('<alt>')
```

result: no error but only moves the tab count inside the editor.

Comment: if possible, then i could add a feature inside [github.com/sl5net/Lintalist4Linux](https://github.com/sl5net/Lintalist4Linux)

Comment: Did you try `keyboard.send_keys("<alt>+<tab>")`?

Comment: @wjandrea `keyboard.send_keys("<alt>+<tab>")` has the same effect like `keyboard.send_keys("<tab>")`  here with Linux Mint Version 20 and 'autokey-gtk autokey-gtk A desktop automation utility for Linux and X11.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: Not directly with our API.

The AutoKey API talks directly to the current active window. So, sending events targeted at the desktop (DTE) will only work if the current active window recognizes them as such and either forwards them to the DTE or emulates what they do.

However, since AutoKey scripts are written in full Python 3, if you can figure out how to do it yourself in Python, AutoKey can run it for you. And, if some other solution is available, you can run it from within an AutoKey script using the `subprocess` module.

Comment: or maybe run a solution with: `os.system(myCmd)`

Comment: @SL5net IIUC, subprocess() is just a newer way of doing the same thing, but I'm not a Python expert.

Answer (score 1):

Autokey's [`Window` class](https://autokey.github.io/lib.scripting.Window-class.html) allows you to [`activate`](https://autokey.github.io/lib.scripting.Window-class.html#activate) a window by name (via [`wmctrl`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl)), among other functionality. Something in that class may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

https://autokey.github.io/api/window.html#autokey.scripting.Window.activate

```
activate(title, switchDesktop=False, matchClass=False)
    Activate the specified window, giving it input focus
```

See more at that page.

Comment: should jump to last window